# operations in artificial neural networks

Tags: neural-network

My question is if we have to use a trained neural network in an algorithm
how to determine its timing complexity? or how many multiplications are done to generate the output?

any comments greatly appreciated. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These might help you to decide.
[NN timing complexity](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_time_complexity_of_Multilayer_Perceptron_MLP_and_other_neural_networks)

And for number of multiplication you may find 
[this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5728/what-is-the-time-complexity-for-training-a-neural-network-using-back-propagation) and [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/amount-of-multiplications-in-a-neural-network-model) useful.

Since you've saved the NN. you just need to test it or just use the NN in feed forward phase. So your calculations seems to be correct. Note that you have to involve the number of testing samples and applying the activation functions in your calculations as well for better describing the behavior of the NN.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So for different architectures we have different number of multiplications? For 20 neurons in one hideen layer we have 15*20+20*2 multis. And for two hidden layer with 10 neurons each, we have 15*10 + 10*10 + 10*2. (i.e.Both have 20 neurons in hidden layer).
Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I dont think the total number of neurons in hidden layer(s) matter. Suppose a NN with 1 input layer 1 output layer and 3 hidden layer. so you'll have 5 layers. and calculate the multiplications for 4 layers (not input layer because nothing is feeding them). [https://hagan.okstate.edu/NNDesign.pdf] This is good reference for neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is not always measured in number of multiplications.

But if this is what you want to want to take as a metric for your complexity, you first need to look in the implementation of nodes you use in your neural network first of all to perform the action of the neuron and than how many multiplications are used for each training-step.

Only After you know all that you can look for the number of nodes and connections in your network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. As i mentioned i'm curios about time complexity of trained and saved NN. if we pass an input vector to it how many multiplications are performed to give the output vector? what do think about my calculations (15*20+20*2)?